# New to Android Studio and encountered unexpected Layout: Android...ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am new to Android Studio. I was following a tutorial where the instructor gives introduction about Android studio using Basic template.

**My result:**

[image: This is the screenshot about where I am stuck with the layout]

**Expected result from tutorial:**

[image: State in tutorial video]

I followed the tutorial word by word, but this was the case from the start of the template. Please help me out.

Comment: Have you included constrain layout dependency - `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'` in build.gradle. Also can you share ui render errors? You can view it by clicking red (!) button on top right corner of UI Layout

Comment: Post the code of activity_main.xml. Also, you have an extra space in the line 7

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.